# Is the phrase "with flying colours" informal

Tags: formal-language, informal-language

As suggested in the title, I wonder if i can use it in my thesis?

I'm discussing the education of spoken English in China, I just thought about the phrase just now, probably I'll be using it like *university students pass reading examinations with fly colours, however, with regards to their performance of speaking..*

This is the first time me doing a thesis so I'm basically unaware of the whole thing.

Comment: What are the subject and title of the thesis, and in what sentence will you use the phrase?

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty  thanks! i just edited it, i haven't written anything about this phrase and I may use it in the context that given in the question

Comment: It seems like a reasonable use to me, but I'm not an academic. Maybe you should check with your instructor to be sure. However, you have to use "with flying colors", as in your title, not "fly colors".

Comment: she may response it with a nah; yeh i missed the ing..